# Java Netbeans open jFrame File Chooser in separate window

Tags: java, netbeans, filechooser

So I'm having a bit of trouble opening up the file chooser from my welcoming jFrame.  Currently I have 1 jFrame called Welcoming.java, and another jFrame called FileChoose.java (not the best names).  Anyways, I've been searching for a long time to find out how I can have my button open the FileChooser, get the file path the person selects and save it in a String variable.

I've checked about 15 different threads and none of them are clear cut.  Anyone else have a good suggestion on how to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up finding a solution to my problem on YouTube.

What I wanted to do was get a directory to save a file at, and I did it by adding this code to my button event:

```
final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode( JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY );
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog( this );

if( returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {
...

}
```

Which opens up the FileChooser and allows you to select a location to save a file.  I stored the file path in a String filePath

```
String filePath = ( chooser.getSelectedFile().toString() + "\\" + textfieldClientName.getText() + ".xls" );
```